# Rails 3 Routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a community_users model that I route in the following way:

```
resources :communities do
  resources :users
end
```

This creates the route `/communities/:id/users/`.

I'd like to configure this route so that only the name of the community with the corresponding :id is shown.

In other words, if a community has an id of '1' and the name 'rails-lovers' - the route would read:

```
/rails-lovers
```

and not:

```
/communities/1/users/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to check out the gem [friendly_id](http://rubygems.org/gems/friendly_id)

That will give you the clean URLs you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not quite sure if this is what you're looking for, but:

One option would be to create the route

```
match ':community_name' => 'users#show_users_for_community'
```

and then in the UsersController have

```
def show_users_for_community
  @community = Community.find_by_name(params[:community_name])
  <do what you need to do here>
end
```

I'm not sure if that route will match too many URLs or not -- it's a very general route.  So if you do this, maybe put it low down in your routes file.